# Linux Drive Mounting

Tags: linux, share, mount

I'm looking for some information and advice on mounting drives in Linux. (openSuSE)

I have the option of CIFS or NFS.

I'd like to clarify if the following is correct.

NFS shares don't need username & password authentication.
CIFS share do need username and password authentication.

When mounting the share is there anyway to ensure the mount has full read / write access ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When mounting the share is there any way to ensure the mount has full read / write access ? 
=> The "mount" command can be used to see existing mounts and their respective options. 
   e.g.

```
[test@myhost test]# mount | grep export
130.35.54.227:/export/LINUX.X64 on /usr/platform type nfs  (ro,tcp,retrans=5,intr,timeo=600,actimeo=1200,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,sloppy,addr=130.35.54.227)
```

In the example above `ro` indicates read only access permission.

Comment: Thanks - is my understanding of NFS / CIFS for credentials correct ?

Comment: NFS does not need username /password. 
CIFS need username/password unless it is using guest.